# Sharepoint 2010 search not showing folders in results

Tags: 2010, search, folder, directory

I am stumped by this pretty unusual problem. One user cannot see folders as results when searching. Only files within the folder are shown. Only one user has this problem. Many other users with the same set of permissions can see folders as search results perfectly fine.

Any pointers as what might be causing this problem?

Answer (score 0):

the bestway i think of check the user permission on the site/doc lib/folder level.

Comment: folder level permission inherits from doc lib level, which inherits from site permissions. The user in question has same permissions as the other users of the site, who can see the folders as results.